# JS making a function with multiple variable and other function

Tags: javascript, function

So, I have following js function which by itself will **NOT** make any sense.

I need to have all the variables and functions (such as `for`) as a separate function that I can call whenever I need:

**Original**

```
function CUSTOM() {
 jQuery(document).on('click', '.rinci_sub', function (e) {
    var something= RMES_CONT(upimg_hold,rinc_cont,upfile_hold);
    var side = "right";     
    var content_total = RINC_INFO(side, gc_current, "now", something);          
    var rmmc_total = RIN_CONTENT(side,content_total,rmmimg);
    for (var i = 0; i < (rup_att_len); i++) {                       
        var rmm_att_name = rupfile[i].substring(rupfile[i].lastIndexOf('/') + 1);   
        var rinc_file = Ab("rinbox_file", upload_dir + rupfile[i], RH("span", "rmmfile chip",  rmm_att_name, ""));                              
        rup_att.push(rinc_file);
    }
  });
};
```

**What I need:**

```
function OTHER(){
    var something= RMES_CONT(upimg_hold,rinc_cont,upfile_hold);
    var side = "right";     
    var content_total = RINC_INFO(side, gc_current, "now", something);          
    var rmmc_total = RIN_CONTENT(side,content_total,rmmimg);
    for (var i = 0; i < (rup_att_len); i++) {                       
        var rmm_att_name = rupfile[i].substring(rupfile[i].lastIndexOf('/') + 1);   
        var rinc_file = Ab("rinbox_file", upload_dir + rupfile[i], RH("span", "rmmfile chip",  rmm_att_name, ""));                              
        rup_att.push(rinc_file);
    }
}   
function CUSTOM_1() {
 jQuery(document).on('click', '.rinci_sub', function (e) {
   OTHER();
  });
};  

function CUSTOM_2() {
 jQuery(document).on('click', '.some_other', function (e) {
   OTHER();
  });
};
```

I know in php, it's alot simpler to make function with variables and other functions. But I am having a hard time making this work.

Could someone show me how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did i understand correctly: you want to pass some varibles to `OTHER` function?

Comment: What is not working?